# Що таке "в корінь дуплаве" та хто такий "виз"?

Tags: значення-слів

У того ж К. Сосенка (Сосенко, Ксенофонт Петрович. Культурно-історична постать староукраїнських свят Різдва і Щедрого Вечера / Ксенофонт Сосенко. – Львів: Накладом авт., 1928. – IX, 349 c.) ще стикнулася з одним текстом:

> Й а в ліску, в ліску, на жовтім піску
> Росте деревце тонке, а в лист широке
> Й а в лист широке, **в корінь дуплаве**,
> Гой у тих кудрях сив соків сидит,
> В Дунай си дивит, там **виза** видит,
> Там виза видит, з визом говорит:
> Гой, ци тепер єк з первовіку?

[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=25328&page=840) пише, що:

> **ДУПЛА́ВИЙ**, **ДУПЛЯ́ВИЙ**, а, е.З дуплом або дуплами.
>
> Стара, дуплява грушка широко розкладала довге гілля (Н. Кобринська)

Виходячи з цього, гіпотетично можна сказати, що „в корінь дуплаве“ — це з дуплом у корені або такий корінь широкий, наче дупло, однак вже повторюватись буде „в лист широке, в корінь широке“, що не логічно. Отож що таке **„в корінь дуплаве“** та хто такий **виз** (про нього інформації не знайшла)?

Comment: Я розумію, але поки зазначаю, що 8. Не знаю, чи це правильно, але у СУМі зазначено, що це 1-8, адже тільки до "М". Тоді як порадите подавати, СУМ-20 чи СУМ-8?

Comment: Я б писав СУМ-20. Словник уже [відомий як СУМ-20](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/СУМ-20) і сам себе [у вступі характеризує як 20-томний](http://www.ulif.org.ua/sites/default/files/vstup_1_8_54.pdf). Це число потрібне не для фіксації того, скільки на якийсь момент часу вже видали томів, а для того, щоб відрізняти його від інших словників із подібними назвами (зокрема СУМ-11). Навіть якщо видавництво принипить видавати нові томи, це нічого не змінить, він залишиться «недовиданим СУМ-20» (аналогічно до того, як «Етимологічний словник української мови: в 7 томах» за 46 років так і не видав том 7).

Comment: А точне зазначення наявної на певний момент часу кількості томів не лише не має практичного сенсу, а й потенційно перешкоджає розрізненню його зі словником 1970-х років, адже при такій схемі йменування новий словник, коли вже видасть том 11, але ще не видасть том 12, теж тимчасово стане «СУМ-11» :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [словнику Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7) знаходимо таке значення:

> **Виз**, **за**, *м*. Рыба Acipensor schypa. Браун. 31.

В [академічному словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyz)

> **ВИЗ**, **а**, *чол*. Велика промислова риба родини осетров их.

А щодо „в корінь дуплаве“, то, думаю, значення цього слова в [академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/duplavyj) досить добре підходить для цього контексту:

> **Дуплавий**, **дуплявий**, **а**, **е**. З дуплом або дуплами. *Де-де заскрипить журавель, затріщить під напором вітру безлиста, дуплава липа* (Іван Франко, VII, 1951, 424); *Дорога до головної вулиці вела.. поміж сади з крислатими дуплавими деревами* (Іван Чендей, Вітер.., 1958, 253); *Стара, дуплява грушка широко розкладала довге гілля* (Наталія Кобринська, Вибр., 1954, 166).

Оскільки, це космогонічна колядка, то дуже важко сучасним дослідникам точно пояснити її смисл. Але, виходячи з розуміння [світового дерева](http://about-ukraine.com/svitove-drevo/):

> По вертикалі древо ділиться на три частини: нижню — коріння (підземний світ), середню — стовбур (земний світ) та верхню — крону (небесний світ). До кожної з цих частин “приписані” певні істоти. Внизу, побіля коріння, мешкають змії, жаби, риби, водоплавні птахи і тварини, бо низ древа символізує не лише підземний світ, а й воду.

то цілком логічно, що в корінні дерева є якесь дупло, де живуть міфологічні істоти (в даному випадку, як я розумію - сокіл).

Comment: Я наводила приклад із СУМу, але от чи справді це підходить для контексту? Бо дерево дуплаве=дерево із дуплами. А от корінь? Перегляньте вище мої думки з приводу цього.

Comment: Пані Оксанко Струс, інформацію щодо вашого коментаря додала у відповідь

Comment: @ОксанкаСтрус, мені здається, корінь дерева цілком може бути дуплавим. Якщо корінь частково визирає з-під землі (а не цілком розташований у землі) і настільки старий/широкий, що в ньому утворилися дупла. (А те, що автор відповіді спочатку просто продублювала тлумачення «дуплявий» із тексту запитання, ніяк не пояснивши це, мене теж було здивувало.)